# Functional Derivative of Product of Two Grassmann Functionals

Tags: functional-analysis, exterior-algebra

Say, I have a product of two Grassmann functionals: $F[\psi(x)]$ and $G[\psi(x)]$ given by $F[\psi(x)]G[\psi(x)]$. I want to take the functional derivative of this product with respect to $\psi(x)$:

$$\frac{\delta}{\delta\psi(x)} \left[ F[\psi(x)]G[\psi(x)] \right].$$

What is the formula for it?

Comment: Left or right functional derivative? :)

Comment: Left functional derivative.